# 16.04 How do I stop Mongo 3.x.x and 4.x.x from complaining about WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'?

Tags: 16.04, mongodb, sysfs

A default installation of MongoDB on Ubuntu 18.04 gives the following warning about transparent hugepage defrag.  How to deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo complains because using transparent hugepage and always defraging it is not optimal for it's performance.  Do your research if you need more info.

A clean permanent solution is to install sysfs and add the setting there.

:~# apt install sysfsutils

add these two lines to /etc/sysfs.conf:

```
kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled = never  
kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag = never
```

reboot